# raspberrypi 3 (minibian): wlan0 doesn't work without eth0 being plugged in to router

Tags: networking, pi-3, ethernet-port, wpa, minibian

I'm customizing my minibian distro and now having hard time to set up two network interfaces: wireless (wlan0) and wired (eth0).

I want eth0 to have a static IP (in case I need to connect it to the network using wires), while wlan0 (set up with wpa_supplicant) to have a dhcp address from my wireless router.

**/etc/network/interfaces:**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.254

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface default inet dhcp
```

**/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf**:

```
# reading passphrase from stdin
network={
  ssid="my_wifi"
  #psk="Password"
  psk=03632d6ca0734abdb5ae1b889f8028552b196f6f7d40e365ebbef7d8d7ac7fee
}
```

The problem: when I connected to my router using cable over eth0, then both my interfaces (wlan0 and eth0) are connected to network - I can ping them both from my other machines.

If I unplug the eth0 in order to have only a wireless connection, then wlan0 also goes down and ping stops response stops.

But if I plug the cable back - I'm getting ping back on both interfaces (eth0 as well as wlan0)

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

So here is the interfaces details when the cable is connected:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:a7:ba:c2
          inet addr:192.168.1.100  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fea7:bac2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1098 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:530 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:73489 (71.7 KiB)  TX bytes:57234 (55.8 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:f2:ef:97
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fef2:ef97/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1410 errors:0 dropped:35 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:26 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:140549 (137.2 KiB)  TX bytes:2792 (2.7 KiB
```

Ip command output:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# ip addr show
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
        inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 ::1/128 scope host
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether b8:27:eb:a7:ba:c2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 192.168.1.100/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fea7:bac2/64 scope link
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether b8:27:eb:f2:ef:97 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 192.168.1.2/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlan0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fef2:ef97/64 scope link
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

root@raspberrypi:~# ip route
default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlan0
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.100
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.2
```

Comment: The    `gateway 192.168.1.254` is nonsense.

It is unclear what  networking system you are expecting to (or actually ) use. You have posted insufficient information to resolve. What is the output of `ifconfig` in both states.

Comment: @Milliways added ifconfig output.. But I'm using ssh to connect and don't have monitor to use with rpi, so in a second state there is no connection and so can't give an output of ifconfig command... lol

Comment: @Milliway also removing gateway changed nothing((

Comment: I did not say to remove it, just that it looked improbable. You have to determine the correct value. I still **really** don't understand **WHY** so many people want to use static addresses. If you removed all the static rubbish and let `DHCP` do its job it should work. You could then run `ip route | grep default | awk '{print $3}'` to determine the correct gateway.

Comment: static address because it's gonna be a server